# How can I increase the size of my window?

Tags: python, tkinter

I know of methods like geometry() or minsize() to set the size of my Tkinter window. But what do I use when I don't want to set the size but instead i.e. want to increase the width by 10.

Comment: You simply keep heigth value and only add 10 to width? Like `geometry("oldWidth+10xoldHeight")`

Comment: How do I the current width/height of my window? I have set a minsize.

Comment: increase the width by 10 _what_? 10 pixels? 10 characters? 10 inches? This sounds like an [xy problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Why do you need to increase it by 10 somethings instead of letting it be its natural size.

Comment: I have a window set to a certain size. Every time I press a button I add another entry field. When I add too many entries they disappear off of the window. So I wanted to increase the size of my window each time I added another entry. Maybe I should have included that in my initial question. Hope that makes it clear, sorry first question. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
w.geometry("{}x{}".format(w.winfo_width() + 10, w.winfo_height()))
```

where `w` is the widget that you want to change the dimensions of

Comment: Ok. Thanks. This was obvious in hindsight. I was initially looking for a method which does exactly that but I assume there is none but this works just fine.

Comment: I did but I couldn't find what I was looking for.